# Select all nodes until a specific given node/tag

Tags: xpath

Given the following markup:

```
<div id="about">
    <dl>
        <dt>Date</dt>
        <dd>1872</dd>
        <dt>Names</dt>
        <dd>A</dd>
        <dd>B</dd>
        <dd>C</dd>
        <dt>Status</dt>
        <dd>on</dd>
        <dt>Another Field</dt>
        <dd>X</dd>
        <dd>Y</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

I'm trying to extract all the `<dd>` nodes following `<dt>Names</dt>` but only until another `<dt>` starts. In this case, I'm after the following nodes:

```
<dd>A</dd>
<dd>B</dd>
<dd>C</dd>
```

I'm trying the following XPath code, but it's not working as intended.

```
xpath("//div[@id='about']/dl/dt[contains(text(),'Names')]/following-sibling::dd[not(following-sibling::dt)]/text()")
```

Any thoughts on how to fix it?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update: much simpler solution

There is a prerequisite in your situation, that is that the anchor item always is the first preceding sibling with a certain property. Because of that, here's a much simpler way of writing the below complex expression:

```
/div/dl/dd[preceding-sibling::dt[1][. = 'Names']]
```

In other words:

- select any `dd`
- that has a first preceding sibling `dt` (the preceding sibling axis counts backwards)
- that itself has a value of "Names"

As can be seen in the following screenshot from oXygen, it selects the nodes you wanted to select (and if you change "Names" to "Status" or "Another Field", it will select only the following ones before the next `dt` also).

[image: screenshot from oXygen of selected nodes]

#### Original complex solution (leaving in for reference)

This is far easier in XPath 2.0, but let's assume you can only use XPath 1.0. The trick is to count the number of preceding siblings from your anchor element (the one with "Names" in it), and disregard any that have the wrong count (i.e., when we cross over `<dt>Status</dt>`, the number of preceding siblings has increased).

For XPath 1.0, remove the comments between `(:` and `:)` (in XPath, whitespace is insignificant, you can make it a multiline XPath for readability, but in 1.0, comments are not possible)

```
/div/dl/dd

    (: any dd having a dt before it with "Names" :)
    [preceding-sibling::dt[. = 'Names']]

    (: count the preceding siblings up to dt with "Names", add one to include 'self' :)
    [count(preceding-sibling::dt[. = 'Names']/preceding-sibling::dt) + 1 
    = 

    (: compare with count of all preceding siblings :)
    count(preceding-sibling::dt)]
```

As a one-liner:

```
/div/dl/dd[preceding-sibling::dt[. = 'Names']][count(preceding-sibling::dt[. = 'Names']/preceding-sibling::dt) + 1 = count(preceding-sibling::dt)]
```

Comment: @André, glad I could be of some help! :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
//dd[preceding-sibling::dt[contains(., 'Names')]][following-sibling::dt]
```

Comment: Nope. That returns all the `<dd>` following `<dt>Names</dt>`: `<dd>A</dd>, <dd>B</dd>, <dd>C</dd>, <dd>on</dd>`.

Comment: I executed this expression, using `oXygen` editor,  and it give me the expected result. `<dd>on</dd>` should not appear in the result. this element doesn't have a following sibling `<dt>`.

Comment: Oh, I see now. You're right. But I've updated the markup in the original question to cater for another scenario in which there is `<dt>Another Field</dt>`. Your code would now return `<dd>on</dd>`, right?